# VMware PowerCLI Variables in ScriptText

Tags: powershell, powercli

Hello I'm having a bit of problem with the Invoke-VMScript cmdlet
I have made a script that creates a virtual Windows 7 machine and then some powershell script executes on the machine for example renaming the computer to the correct name.

But if I run

```
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText {(Get-Wmiobject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename($strName)}
```

The $strName variable doesn't get resolved, anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your haven't correctly scoped your variable.  Here's a simple experiment you can try in your console:

```
PS C:\> $test = "Resolve!"
PS C:\> $test
Resolve!

# This scriptblock will not resolve the variable.
PS C:\> {$test}
$test

# This scriptblock will resolve the variable.
PS C:\> [scriptblock]::Create($test)
Resolve!
```

Invoke-VMScript's [documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI51/html/Invoke-VMScript.html) suggests you should pass `-ScriptText` as a string instead of a [ScriptBlock](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx). So in this case, we can mimic example 2:

```
$string = "(Get-Wmiobject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename($strName)"
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $string
```

Variables enclosed by `" "` will be resolved.

Comment: Hmmhmhm dumb of me to not RTFM
But when I pass it as a string I get an errormessage saying I am missing ')' in final method call.

    $strScript = "(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem).Rename($strName)" 
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $strScript

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error.  Make sure the contents of `$strName` isn't breaking anything, or otherwise look up how `Invoke-VMScript` escapes characters and make sure it isn't breaking your input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a guest handy for renaming, but following [LucD](http://www.lucd.info/2010/05/07/changing-vmware-tools-scripts/), here's a working example using variables to build up input for scriptText:

```
$svcName = "vmtools"
$guestScript = 'get-wmiObject win32_service | where {$_.name -eq "' + $svcName + '"}'
Invoke-VMScript -vm myVMname -scriptText $guestScript
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Rename Computer command line script
$renamecomputer = "wmic path win32_computersystem where ""Name='%computername%'"" CALL     rename name='$VM'"
#Send command line script to GuestOS
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VM -GuestUser $GU -GuestPassword $GP -ScriptType Bat -ScriptText   $renamecomputer
```

This is what i use for my renaming script.
Works well

Answer (score 0):

I got this working:

```
Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText "(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).rename(""${vmName}"")"
```